# How to wrap an existing readable store to add extra parameters?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-store

I am new to Svelte. I'm trying to wrap a small wrapper around svelte-i18n to allow relative translation key.

This is how the library can be used:

```html
<script>
import { _ } from 'svelte-i18n';
</script>

<p>{$_('absolute_key')}</p>
```

What I would like to achieve

```html
<script>
import { tr } from "my_wrapper.js"

const _ = tr("base.path.relative");
</script>

<p>{$_('.relative_key')}</p>
```

Closest I was able to achieve is

```js
// my_wrapper.js
import { _ } from 'svelte-i18n';

export const tr = (basePath) => (path, options = {}) => {
  let returnVal;
  if (path.startsWith(".")) {
    _.subscribe((t) => returnVal = t(`${basePath}${path}`, options));
  } else {
    _.subscribe((t) => returnVal = t(path, options));
  }
  return returnVal;
}
```

It kinda work but I have to omit the `$` sign in `{$_('.relative_key')}`. Is there a way to keep its usage with a dollar sign as if I was using the default API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented exactly that before, you just have to return a function from the store. Looks something like this:

```js
// better name for _
import { format } from 'svelte-i18n';

export function section(path) {
    const { subscribe } = derived(
        format,
        $format => (idOrMessage, options) => {
            if (typeof idOrMessage == 'string')
                return $format(`${path}.${idOrMessage}`, options);

            return $format(
                {
                    ...idOrMessage,
                    id: `${path}.${idOrMessage.id}`
                },
                options,
            );
        },
    );

    return {
        path,
        subscribe,
        // allows chaining
        section: (subPath) => section(`${path}.${subPath}`),
    }
}
```

Would recommend not including the joining `.` anywhere except the internals, it's pretty ugly otherwise.

```html
<script>
  // ...
  const s = section('section');
  const sub = s.section('subSection');
  // or
  const sub2 = section('section.subSection');
</script>

Should be equivalent:
{$_('section.subSection.value')}
{$s('subSection.value')}
{$sub('value')}
{$sub2('value')}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d83cb17b237d4ab9a814494c8095f418?version=4.2.0)

Comment: Brilliant! Took me sometime to understand but now I get it! Everything works perfectly!